Updating the side yard with pavers and planers. Looking for feedback/input on foundation
I’m wanting to fix up my side yard that leads to our patio. The general idea is to use the existing concrete foundation as my base and add sand, pavers, poly, etc (Following a recommended YouTube) to build a walking path that goes to the patio. The left side drains, and I’d like to build thin planters with local plants and climbers. The patio is 6” higher than the concrete pathway and it drives me crazy. I want this redesign to address that jarring step by either a subtle step or slope.
Also, I’m new to landscaping but moderately handy. I want to DIY as much as possible to learn, and I don’t mind throwing money at good tools that will help or material that will really add polish.
 
Questions:

Is my plan sound? If not, I’d appreciate any and all feedback. Same goes for input on a new idea or direction.
Should I be concerned about that cracking concrete that I’ll be using as a base? My gut says yes, but I’m hoping I’m wrong.

 
Pictures

Current area. Driveway is in front and patio/backyard behind
Mock up of plan with notes.
6” lip mentioned
The other side and most of the patio. The side yard is on the far right  note: it looks dated, but we’re getting all new furniture and potentially staining or paving over the existing concrete.

 
Dimensions
Concrete width is 41”
Rock area width is 9”
Total width 50"
Length to gate is 30ft
Height difference from patio 6”
 
Location & Climate
Southern California (Torrance) Zone 10b
Thanks!

60:1 (1.6%) slope for 6" rise in 30 feet seems fine.

Depending on paver thickness, you may need to replace or reset your gate at a higher elevation.  Also, is the wall on the left a freestanding wall (i.e. basically a concrete fence) or a retaining wall?

It’s a concrete wall on the property line. Thanks for the help so far

Please revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips. Put all new information in your question, not down here in comments.
